# Enforced Password Change

Tags: security, password-manager

Many services on the internet do not **enforce** two-factor, or even updating passwords at intervals. I'm looking for an application that is capable of advising when you should update your password, and also test.

For example, the application detects that "[Facebook](http://www.facebook.com)" hasn't forced a password change in 90 days and will prompt you to update (of course, it cannot do it on your behalf). It then once you update it within the application (similar to like a password manager) can launch a browser and attempt to login; I know this could be a security flaw, so it's okay if it *doesn't* have this function, and just a reminder.

Alternatively (**or** with as a preference) should prompt you to advise that "Service Blah" supports MFA/Multi-Factor authentication and advise you to set it up. How it would go about detecting you use this application should be based on you having some form of login information stored in the application, or to search a pre-defined (by you) username.

**Needs**

- Run on **at least** Android or Windows
- Support encrypted data *if* it stores passwords or login information

Comment: Related work that could be awesome if implemented, some API to [Have I been Pwnd?](https://haveibeenpwned.com/)